# Film where man pours black liquid into tank of Rolls Royce which then transforms

Tags: story-identification, movie

The only only scene I recall was that this young man around 20 was late for work, and the only car I can find to describe his car is the rolls Royce phantom. Next he pours some of the black liquid into the engine and his car becomes better and faster, and he gets to work on time.

I believe it was a black and white movie, the man was Caucasian and had black hair; I suppose it was a black car as well. I think he made this black liquid but only had one vial of it, so he was trying to save as much as possible. He wasn't happy to use it for the car, but he knew he had to though. I know it made the car run better, but I don't know if he drank it himself.

Comment: Live-action movie? When/where did you see it? Physical appearance of the young man, color of the car? The more detail we have, the quicker we can find it.

Comment: I believe it was a black and white movie, the man was caucasian and had black hair, I suppose black car as well. I think he made this black liquid but only had one vial of it, so he was trying to save as much as possible. He wasn't happy to use it for the car he new he had to though. I know it made the car run better. But idk if he drank himself. Rigt now I'm just trying to say as much as possible.

Comment: Live-action as well sorry

Comment: Was it a silent film? Parts of *City Lights* fit up with your description, with The Tramp borrowing the Rolls Royce of a wealthy man, and the plot line of being late to work.